# How to transform mesh components?

Tags: mathematics, unity, matrix, transformation

I am attempting to transform the components of a mesh directly using a 4x4 matrix. This is working for the vertex positions, but it is not working for the normals (and probably not the tangents either).

Here is what I have:

```
// Transform vertex positions - Works like a charm!
vertices = mesh.vertices;
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; ++i)
    vertices[i] = transform.MultiplyPoint(vertices[i]);

// Does not work, lighting is messed up on mesh
normals = mesh.normals;
for (int i = 0; i < normals.Length; ++i)
    normals[i] = transform.MultiplyVector(normals[i]).normalized;

// Tangents?? I really do not understand these guys
tangents = mesh.tangents;
for (int i = 0; i < tangents.Length; ++i) {
    Vector4 temp = transform.MultiplyVector(tangents[i]).normalized;
    temp.w = tangents[i].w;
    tangents[i] = temp;
}
```

Note: The input matrix converts from local to world space and is needed to combine multiple meshes together.

Comment: If your normal matrix does not have uniform scale (ie same amount of scale in x,y,z directions), [then it will screw up the normals](http://explodedbrain.livejournal.com/112906.html).

Comment: @bobobobo Should I have a different matrix for normals then? The built-in Unity `Mesh.CombineMeshes` seems to work fine with the same input matrix. But obviously it could be creating a normal matrix or something. Are you suggesting that I should be using `transform.inverse.transpose.MultiplyVector` instead?

Comment: Definitely don't do it like that!  You'll be inverting the matrix for every vector you need to multiply.  Try creating a second matrix `normalMatrix = transform.inverse().transpose()` and see if that solves your problem.  A tangent is just a vector that "grazes" the surface.

Comment: @bobobobo: you should probably write that as an answer.

Comment: Awesome that seems to work! The lighting behaves a little differently from the original meshes in that they detect the light at different stages. But the normals appear to behave correctly and I am guessing that the tangents are also (though the `w` component might be messed up)... cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your normal matrix does not have uniform scale (ie same amount of scale in x,y,z directions), then [it will screw up the normals](http://explodedbrain.livejournal.com/112906.html).

Try creating a second matrix `normalMatrix = transform.inverse().transpose()` and see if that solves your problem. A tangent is just a vector that "grazes" the surface.